# Why is $\arctan(\sqrt{3}) \ne \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$?

Tags: trigonometry

Following the goniometric properties for $\tan$, $\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3}\right) = \sqrt{3}$.

According to this formula

$$\arctan (x) = y $$ and $$\tan(y) = x$$

If we let $x = \sqrt{3}$ then isn't the only option for $y=\dfrac{\pi}{3}$ ?
Or is it just the sign that is the problem in this case?

Comment: " *goniometric* properties"? And $\;\arctan\sqrt 3=\frac\pi3+k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\;$ , since $\;\tan\left(\frac\pi3+k\pi\right)=\sqrt3\;$

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a native English speaker, I don't know the correct terminology.

Comment: $\arctan(x) = y$ where $x=\sqrt{3}$ and $y=\pi / 3$. Where would the equality in the title come from?

Comment: "Goniometric" means "of our relating to the measurement of angles"; it's not the proper English term,  but it is English nonetheless. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\tan(\pi/3) = \sqrt{3}$.  By definition (if we're dealing with real numbers and using the usual "principal value" arctan) $\arctan(\sqrt{3})$ is the unique number $x$ with $-\pi/2 < x < \pi/2$ and $\tan(x) = \sqrt{3}$,
and that is $\pi/3$.

Answer (score 0):

$\tan$ is periodic, so if $\tan(y) = x$ then also $\tan(y + k \pi) = x$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.